# Reformatting array in foreach

Tags: php, arrays, json, facebook-graph-api

I'm working now on graph api of facebook, where they give me a json/array response. What i need to do is to reformat the json since i'm not comfortable using their format.
This is my sample json response:

```
"ids": [
    {
      "id": "id1",
      "format": [
        {
          "filter": "130x130",
          "picture": "sample1.jpg",
        },
        {
          "filter": "130x130",
          "picture": "sample1.jpg",
        }
      ]
   },
      {
      "id": "id2",
      "format": [
        {
          "filter": "130x130",
          "picture": "sample2.jpg",
        },
        {
          "filter": "130x130",
          "picture": "sample2.jpg",
        }
      ]
     }
]
```

PHP codes:

```
$sampleArray = //let say this is the array sample above
$dataArray = array();
$dataArrayNested = array();
foreach($sampleArray['ids'] as $key => $value){
   $dataArrayNested[$key] = $value['id'];
   $dataArrayNested[$key] = $value['format'][0]['picture']
}
$dataArray['ids'] =  $dataArrayNested;
```

But when i print out the result:

```
{
  "ids": [
    "id1",
    "sample1.jpg",
    "id2",
    "sample2.jpg"
  ]
}
```

This result is not really what i want. It should be like this:

```
{
      "ids": [
        {
        "id": "id1",
        "format" : "sample1.jpg"
        },
        {
        "id": "id1",
        "format" : "sample1.jpg"
        }
      ]
    }
```

I know there is something wrong in my codes..

Comment: make your json valid: parse it online [https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: my json sample is just only sample for my question. the real one on my codes is valid

Comment: If you make at least one valid portion of json then we can check it.

Comment: why not use array_map for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you PHP code in **line 4** you're refering to `$key` which is numeric non-relevant.

I think what you're looking for something like:

```
<?php
foreach($sampleArray['ids'] as $value){
   $key = $value['id'];
   if (!isset($dataArrayNested[$key])) $dataArrayNested[$key] = array();

   $dataArrayNested[$key]['id'] = $value['id'];
   $dataArrayNested[$key]['format'] = $value['format'][0]['picture'];
}
```